# Swift Mailer Error Log in lib/classes/Swift/Transport/EsmtpTransport.php

Tags: php, swiftmailer, mailer

I have a new installation of Swift Mailer.  When sending emails it fails and in the .errorlog file I have the following:

[25-Jun-2019 09:51:32 America/Detroit] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '?' in /home/qetbcdfu/public_html/swift/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/EsmtpTransport.php on line 213

Help appreciated!

```
require_once 'lib/swift_required.php';
// Create the Transport
$transport = (new Swift_SmtpTransport('mail.authsmtp.com', 25))
->setUsername('hidden')
->setPassword('hidden');
// Create the Mailer using your created Transport
$mailer = new Swift_Mailer($transport);
// Create a message
$themessage .= "<p>Hi this is an email message that is a test message from Cedine's Swift AuthSMTP programming interface.  I hope you have enjoyed receiving this message.</p><p><strong>Please delete this message.</strong></p>"; 
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance('An Invitation to Join the Global CHE Network')
      ->setFrom('jim@jimnull.com')
      ->setTo(array('jsnull@outlook.com', 'jnull1955@gmail.com'))
      ->setBody($themessage, 'text/html');  
// Send the message
$result = $mailer->send($message);  
print "<p>Sent</p>";
```

Comment: I've changed my code and I now get the following error_log message...

Answer (score 0):

I think you run on php 5.6 since the error is on a php 7.x operator.

As we can see in the source code on [line 213](https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/blob/1182ede0b254b6a4f12763f48ff25a96f139ac71/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/EsmtpTransport.php#L213%20%60%60%60) they use `??` operator. This operator is available from php 7.x as is mentioned in the [php docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.coalesce)

Since php 5.6 is already [end of life](https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php) you should look into upgrading to a newer version of php

Comment: Yes you are right I was on 5.6 and upgraded to 7.0.  I now get the following error message:

[25-Jun-2019 10:19:25 America/Detroit] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Swift_Message::newInstance() in /home/qetbcdfu/public_html/swift/swifttest.php:43
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /home/qetbcdfu/public_html/swift/swifttest.php on line 43

Comment: @JamesS.Null what you can do is this: ```$message = (new \Swift_Message($subject))
                ->setFrom('email@email', 'email')``` from there you can do all the things  you want to do with the message

Comment: Thank you @Perry